# WCF Service is not working properly

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, tomcat, iis

I'm going to access WCF service which is hosted from IIS Manager (IIS 7.5). Client is a java application and it is deployed in a tomcat server. When I tried to access WCF service, tomcat displays a SOAPFaultException saying "Unable to initialise Settings property. This is most likely due to a missing config file". WCF service is hosted in local machine and can be accessed through browser. And also client stubs was generated using "wsimport" without getting any errors and warnings.

But, When I ran WCF service from visual studio, it worked properly. I'm not familiar with .net and can't figure out what was missed.

(There are service.svc file, web.config file and bin folder with dlls are placed in the physical path)
Here is the service model in Web config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="ABC_WCF.ABCDrugService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FDB_WCF.IABCDrugService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't already, add logging to your service, log the exceptions and check the call stack to find why and where the service crashes. You may be missing a config section in your configuration file. The message seems to be custom. Do you throw an exception with this message somewhere in your code? Search for the message string

Comment: If the exception is coming from the Tomcat server, then I would check the settings there.  It doesn't strike me as being an issue with the service.   However, you can also try go to the service in a browser, to see if the You've created a service page comes up.

Comment: But the problem is when I ran the service from Visual studio, it works properly with tomcat. Problem comes when I tried to host is using IIS manager. @Tim I can access the service using the browser